# Firestore: Turning off onSnapshot listener doesn't work based on function argument

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my webapp with Firestore (Firebase 9) I have the following code which should turn off a realtime listener based on the argument in the getRecentProfilesExternal() function. It works in ACTION1 but not in ACTION2.

Strangely, I get the "unsubscribed" alert in ACTION2 although the listener remains active.

Thanks for any help!

```
//Get profiles and update them in realtime

    //The command param determines if the function should subscribe to changes (leave the onSnapshot listener on), 
    //or unsubscribe (in order to limit Firestore reads), usually when another listener is turned on instead

    const getRecentProfilesExternal = (command) => {


        //Get loggedin user data
        const auth = getAuth();
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            if (user) {


              //Get last 20 profiles: initial render and listen to changes
              const qProfiles = query(collection(db, "candidateprofiles"), where("useridprimary", "==", store.state.currentUserId));
              //initial data fetch and listen to Firestore collection changes
              const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(qProfiles, (snapshot) => {
                store.state.currentProfileList = []
                snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                  let profile = doc.data()
                  profile.id = doc.id
                  store.state.currentProfileList.push(profile)
                })
              })

              //ACTION 1
              setTimeout(() => {
                unsubscribe()
              }, 5000);

              //ACTION 2
              if(command == "unsubscribe") {
                //this turns the onSnapshot listener off
                unsubscribe()
                alert("unsubscribed")
              }
              else {
                //do nothing, this will keep the onSnapshot listener turned on
              }

   
            } else {
                //user not signed in
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: So I just realised that when I call the function a second time, it subcribes, then ubsubscribes to a new listener. But the old listener is still active. Now my problem is how to fire unsubcribe() later, when the function has already run a first time to turn the listener on? I don't have access to unsibscribe() outside of the function.

Comment: So I solved it by declaring a global variable called unsubscribe. This variable is then assigned the onSnapshot code in the initial function. Now I can create a second function that runs the unsubscribe as it has global scope. Not very elegant but I don't see a better way right now.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @jeff3546  -- To make that clear to the system too, can you post your solution (including the relevant code changes) as an answer below? That way others are also more likely to benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just realised that when I call the function a second time, it subcribes, then ubsubscribes to a new listener. But the old listener is still active. So now my problem was how to fire unsubscribe() later, when the function has already run a first time to turn the listener on. I didn't have access to unsibscribe() outside of the function.

So I solved it by declaring a global variable called unsubscribeToRecentProfiles. This variable is then assigned the onSnapshot code in the initial function. Now I can create a second function that runs the unsubscribe as it has global scope. Not very elegant but I don't see a better way right now. This is my solution:

```html
let unsubscribeToRecentProfiles;

  //Get profiles and update them in realtime
  const getRecentProfiles = () => {

      //Get loggedin user data
      const auth = getAuth();
      onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
          if (user) {

            const qProfiles = query(collection(db, "candidateprofiles"), where("useridprimary", "==", store.state.currentUserId));
            unsubscribeToRecentProfiles = onSnapshot(qProfiles, (snapshot) => {
              store.state.currentProfileList = []
              snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                let profile = doc.data()
                profile.id = doc.id
                store.state.currentProfileList.push(profile)
              })
            })

          } else {
              //user not signed in
          }
      });
  }

  unsubscribeToRecentProfiles()
```